# Error while building for iOS from Unity in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, error-handling, xcode7

I'm getting this error which is causing a build fail in Xcode after building the project from Unity:

```
fatal error: lipo: can't write to output file: /Users/applemac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hdkycurnjlkvikcljdgvlfnbmsua/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/spacegame.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/spacegame.lipo (Undefined error: 0)
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?
The app is for iPhone and iPad if it makes any difference. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this sudden? Did it used to work but stopped?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode and/or your Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it to work, I just made a simple change in my Project target-> Build setting-> Build Active Architecture only and set this Build Active Architecture only to YES. And it's working fine now..

another think you can try is -> 
Again I face this issue after updating. This time I have to update Project target-> Build setting->Valid Architecture to armv7. I removed armv7s and arm64.

the third thing which might work -> delete your application and run a new build

plz tell me the result

Comment: Thankyou - I will try these out and let you know.

Comment: which one was useful?

Comment: Didn't take long! I set the Build Active Architecture to YES and no luck, but this as well as removing armv7s and arm64 made it build. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just changed the Build Active Architecture only to YES. it is working perfectly fine. thanks @engmasha